# Cómo generar código de barras solo con barras en formato SVG

Tags: python, django

Tengo un problema, estoy usando la librería `python-barcode` en un proyecto Django, pero al generar el código de barras, siempre me agrega el número de entrada en la parte de abajo de las barras.

Quisiera generar el codigo de barras solo con las barras, que no me agregue los numeros abajo de las barras, es posible hacer eso?. Este es mi código actual:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.core.files import File

from .models import Orden

#third party
import barcode
from barcode.writer import SVGWriter
from io import BytesIO


@receiver(post_save, sender=Orden)
def generate_barcode(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.barcode = str(instance.id).zfill(13)
        COD128 = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
        rv = BytesIO()
        COD128(f'{instance.barcode}', writer=SVGWriter()).write(rv)
        instance.barcode_file.save(f'{instance.barcode}.svg', File(rv), save=False)
        instance.save()
```

Comment: Recuerda que si te sirvió la respuesta aquí planteada, debes marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te falto fue usar el argumento adicional al crear la instancia de la clase barcode.writer.SVGWriter() debes poner false el text y esto le indica a la biblioteca que no incluya el texto debajo de las barras del código de barras.

Modifica la línea donde creaste la instancia del SVG:

```
COD128(f'{instance.barcode}', writer=SVGWriter(text=False)).write(rv)
```

Comment: Lo intenté, pero no acepta el argumento `text`

SVGWriter.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'

Busqué mucho, pero al parecer esta librería no contempla el código de barra sin los números abajo.